# How to convert David Lowe keypoints into OpenCV keypoints?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I want to use [siftfast](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libsift/files/libsiftfast/libsiftfast-1.2/) for computing SIFT keypoints and then use them in OpenCV.

The `Keypoint` structure is defined in `siftfast.h` as:

```
typedef struct KeypointSt {
    float row, col;             // Subpixel location of keypoint.
    float scale, ori;           // Scale and orientation (range [-PI,PI])
    float descrip[128];     // Vector of descriptor values
    struct KeypointSt *next;    // Pointer to next keypoint in list.
} *Keypoint;
```

While the consturctor of opencv keypoints is:

```
KeyPoint (float x, float y, float _size, float _angle=-1, float _response=0, int _octave=0, int _class_id=-1)
```

Now, I have to find a way to map the siftfast's `Keypoint` into OpenCV's `KeyPoint`:

- `row` == `x`
- `col` == `y`

But what about the other values? Can you help me this conversion?

Comment: If you don't find a better answer, you can always run both detectors, then compare and extrapolate for matching points.

Comment: @Photon this is not a solution since they produce different values :(

Comment: Of course they produce different values.  But at least for some of the key-points, they should refer to the same image feature.  If you can somehow identify those, you would probably see a pattern of a transformation for the values of scale and orientation.  Given that both implementations share a core method, it should be doable.  If not with any given image, perhaps with a synthetically generated image that provokes a required response.